# Checkstyle for Python

Tags: java, python, coding-style

Is there an application similar to Java's [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) for Python?

By which I mean, a tool that analyzes Python code and can be run as part of continuous integration (e.g. CruiseControl or Hudson). After analyzing, it should produce an online accessible report which outlines any problems found in the code.

Thank you,

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are actually a lot of tools:
as other have said

- pylint : very very strict (imho too much), yet customizable
- pep-8 : very good
- pychecker
- pyflakes: extremely fast, perfect when used in emacs with flymake.

To format your code according to pep8 I can suggest you [PythonTidy](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PythonTidy)

Answer (score 6):

You may look at [pylint](http://www.logilab.org/857) to see if it fits you needs.

Answer (score 6):

Besides pylint:

the [pep-8](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8) tool

Answer (score 1):

Besides pylint and pep-8: [pychecker](http://pychecker.sourceforge.net/)